# Monitoring & Alerting on production applications

Tags: performance, architecture, monitoring

I've been looking for a discussion on ways to monitor and alert on production applications for a little while now, but haven't found any overwhelming information.

I'm in the process of converting a behemoth of an application into smaller microservices and thought now would be a great time to implement some better monitoring of this application. What are some ways, ideally without using paid applications, to monitor the health of the overall application, and individual microservices?

Some possibilities I've considered.
- Building a small application that periodically checks or receives heartbeats.
- Setting up logstash with kabana on openstack to monitor various logs that the services spit out.

Aaaannnddd that's about all I got.

Answer (score 4):

We're running a fairly large environment (hundreds of servers) which is microservices/docker based, multi-tier, highly available and completely elastic.

When it comes to monitoring and alerting, we're using two different tools:

- **Nagios** for availability monitoring - it basically sends us an email if a service is down, lacks resources or suffers from any other problem which prevents it from operating
- **ELK** - We use it to find the root cause of the problem and to alert about issues, trends before they actually impact the application/business.

So when there is a significant issue, Nagios will alert and we will jump into the Log analytics console to try to find the problem. In some cases, the ELK will alert when issues start to build up before it is seen on Nagios. That way we can prevent the issue from deteriorating. You can read more about setting your own ELK setup on AWS here - http://logz.io/blog/deploy-elk-production/

There are obviously many commercial tools for both monitoring, alerting and log analytics but since you're looking for free/open-source tools I've recommended these.

**As a disclaimer, I'm the CEO and Co-Founder of Logz.io which amongst other things offers Enterprise-ELK as a service

Answer (score 2):

There are two elements to monitoring:

Availability - will it work
Performance - is it working properly

Availability is easy, there are hundreds of tools which do synthetic transactions. You can use a service (I can provide a specific life, but there are so many out there from pingdom, to site 24x7, to various other point solutions)

If you want to understand performance have a look at the APM technologies. THey range from more simplistic tracing products which look at the end user and component level performance to more sophisticated tools which actually stitch the whole transaction path together including the browser data.

Gartner has research on both of these markets (I wrote a lot of it before I left). I work for a company AppDynamics which does all of the above in a single product including application availability and performance (mobile or web). We offer the solution SaaS or you can install it internally. FInally we also pull the data together including logs into a backend.

You can build availability monitoring and log collection, you can also collect client side data and other telemetry you emit, but there is no good open source APM tooling out there for a true transaction tracing technology. Also how much time do you want to spend managing ELK, opentsdb, graphite, statsd, collectd, Nagios, etc etc to get this done...

Comment: https://github.com/naver/pinpoint

This pinpoint project looks very promising to do APM. and transaction tracing in distributed app.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to monitor your production servers, you can go with some of the free limited server monitor like Nagios which is hard to configure and not as simple to work. Or you can look at some of the players in this market like Stackify, LogicMonitor or several others. If you want additional tools like code level monitoring, then you'll need to look on vendors that provide APM (application performance management) such as Stackify, New Relic, AppDynamics You'll find vast price differences and features, so it is really about what are your requirements.